# php array merge, keep values from first array, fill in the gaps

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge 2 arrays with following structure:
$primary_array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Gold
            [price] => 150.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Silver
            [price] => 75.00
        )

)
```

$secondary_array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Gold
            [price] => 100.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Silver
            [price] => 75.00
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Bronze
            [price] => 50.00
        )
)
```

expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Gold
            [price] => 150.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Silver
            [price] => 75.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Bronze
            [price] => 50.00
        )
)
```

Pricefrom primary array must take over the secondary array, but fill in the missing data from secondary array.

I tried to use

```
array_unique(array_merge($primary_array,$secondary_array), SORT_REGULAR)
```

but it did not produce expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few choices.

Check out 
array_replace_recursive http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

array_merge_recursive http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php